# Download files hosted on elastic beanstalk

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My current application is updating JSON files on the amazon elastic beanstalk server. Is there any way to download the current files on the server or access those JSON files??

Just wondered if I can access them before restructuring my server to host those files elsewhere or on a DB.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions in:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html
you can download the files using the following code for this purpose:
scp -i key_file.pem ec2-user@ec2_IP_Address:/remote/dir/foobar.txt /local/dir